# How to get file path from content uri in android pie

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, path, uri, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to upload an image using retrofit 2.0. After obtaining the uri in `onActivityResult`, I am trying to get the path from the uri, which is giving null. The same code works perfectly in pre-lollipop devices.

```
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Image.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(inputUri,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
   String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
   cursor.close();
// filePath is always null
   if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
       file = new File(filePath);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you added permissions to Manifest?

Comment: read this article https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954

Comment: @AntonisRadz Yes. I've included permissions. I was using inputstream before and it was working. For moving into retrofit, i decided to use this approach and its not working.

Comment: @Mr.Bunny Am doing everything mentioned in the article. I was using input stream to get file before. Now decided to get it from uri, and for that am using the above given function, which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fully working code for taking last picture from content provider working on all apis:

```
      public ArrayList<String> getNewPicturesUri(JobParameters parameters) {
    ArrayList<String> newPictures = new ArrayList<>();

    if (parameters.getTriggeredContentAuthorities() != null) {
        if (parameters.getTriggeredContentUris() != null) {
            ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Uri uri : parameters.getTriggeredContentUris()) {
                List<String> path = uri.getPathSegments();
                if (path != null && path.size() ==
                        Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPathSegments().size() + 1) {
                    ids.add(path.get(path.size() - 1));
                }
            }

            if (ids.size() > 0) {
                StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
                    if (selection.length() > 0) {
                        selection.append(" OR ");
                    }
                    selection.append(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID);
                    selection.append("='");
                    selection.append(ids.get(i));
                    selection.append("'");
                }

                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    String[] projection = new String[]{
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};

                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, selection.toString(), null, null);

                    if (cursor != null) {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            newPictures.add(cursor.getString(PROJECTION_DATA));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException exception) {
                    FirebaseCrash.report(exception);
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newPictures;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is selection.toSrting(), while getting the cursor. Passed it as null, got the same error again.

Comment: I updated answer. I am using this method in Job Service to get notified about new pictures in phone. Hope it can help you

Comment: Where should i use the inputUri which i got after picking file from device?

Comment: can you please tell whole situation why you need it and post more code

Comment: I found the issue. Using contentResolver, we can't get path directly it seems. Need to copy into cache and then do it.

Comment: This link helped me fix it : https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/blob/master/collect_app/src/main/java/org/odk/collect/android/utilities/MediaUtils.java